# How to find the linear equivalent of a min{} constraint?

Tags: optimization, programming

I am facing a problem where I need to linearize the constraints to get an LP formulation.

The objective:

$ max_{x\in X, s_i \in R, \lambda \leq 0}   \sum_{j=1}^N s_j + \epsilon\lambda $

s.t.

$ s_j + \lambda ||\xi_j - \xi_i||^2 \geq min_{l=1..L} \{a_l \xi_i^Tx + b_l\}$ $\forall i,j$

If you have any idea of how to linearize this constraint, please tell me. If the inequality was in the other way around, I could do it but now I'm stuck.

Comment: It is nonconvex, and you need binary variables to linearize the right-hand side, do you realize that?

Comment: I think it is convex. Could you highlight your argument please?

Comment: Well it is not. Draw the function $\min(0,x)$ as the most trivial example to see that it is a concave function, and thus the constraint is not convex.

Comment: Yes sure, I do not really see the difference between concave and convex, they are simply the opposite, You told me about binaries, can you tell me a bit more?

Comment: Then you really have to read up on convexity and optimization because it is (to a large extent) the difference between tractable and intractable. $f(x) \leq 0$ is a convex set if $f(x)$ is convex or equivalently $f(x) \geq 0 $ is a convex set if $f(x)$ is concave.

Comment: I do not pretend to know a lot in convex optimization, and my course is about linear programming, that is why we are trying to linearize the problem. Do you have any potential idea to help me out?

Comment: If you are taking a course on linear programming, and not mixed-integer programming with binaries, you have an error in the description, as the model isn't LP-representable. Perhaps you switched the inequality, or it is supposed to be \max.

Comment: Actually, it is rather evident that you have an error in the problem definition as the model as you write it is unbounded, as I simply can set $s_j = \infty$ and have feasibility and inifinite objective.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have a mistake in the model derivation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To model $y = \min z$ using a linear model, one simple model is to enumerate the possible cases, either $y = z_1$ or $y = z_2$ etc, and the constraint that $y$ must be smaller than all elements.

Introduce $n$ binary variables $d_i$, and the combinatorial model is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n d_i = 1\\
d_1 \rightarrow y = z_1\\
d_2 \rightarrow y = z_2\\\vdots\\
d_n \rightarrow y = z_n\\
y \leq z
$$

The implications are modelled using standard big-M strategy $-M(1-d_i) \leq y-z_i \leq M(1-d_i)$